# Как загрузить изображение по ftp из picturebox c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Приветствую, такой вопрос:

```
FileStream some_stream = File.OpenRead("путь и название файла");
```

`File.OpenRead` требует путь и название загружаемого файла. Как его получить, если я хочу загрузить изображение по фтп, которое у меня в данный момент вставлено в picturebox? То есть, физически оно у меня находится только в winforms, никуда более не сохраненное.

Comment: "Загрузить изображение по ftp, вставленное в PictureBox?" Это вообще как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я понимаю, что автора вопроса давно нет на сайте, и вопрос немного странный, но он имеет обоснование и решение, надеюсь оно кому-нибудь пригодится.

Для начала отвечу на вопрос из комментария:

> "Загрузить изображение по ftp, вставленное в PictureBox?" Это вообще как?

`PictureBox` имеет свойство - **[ImageLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.imagelocation(v=vs.100).aspx)**, которое позволяет указать путь или URL-адрес отображаемого изображения. При этом не требуется указывать значение в свойстве `Image`, потому что оно будет получено автоматически. Разумеется если адрес верный и изображение доступно.

Поэтому ни какой мистики тут нет, вполне реально получить адрес изображения любым доступным способом, хоть программным, хоть "копи-пастом" и получить картинку в `PictureBox` не имея собственно файла картинки.

Теперь очередь автора вопроса:

**Как сохранить изображение полученное таким образом**

Так как изображение считывается напрямую с источника, файла разумеется нет, просто при каждой загрузке формы изображение считывается с указанного адреса и формируется объект класса `Image`, который доступен через одноименное свойство `PictureBox`.

Для сохранения нужно обратиться к этому объекту и воспользоваться методом `Save`. При этом есть возможность указать формат сохраняемого файла, а это фактически дает возможность конвертации форматов изображений полученных из сети в нужный формат.

Ну и демонстрационный пример, куда же без него:

```
public class PictureForm : Form
{
    public PictureForm()
    {
        PictureBox demoPictureBox = new PictureBox();
        demoPictureBox.Parent = this;
        demoPictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        demoPictureBox.ImageLocation = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuN8J.png";
        demoPictureBox.Click += (sender, e) => 
            (sender as PictureBox).Image.Save("h:\\test.gif", ImageFormat.Gif);
    }
}
```

Как видите, свойство `Image` не используется для установки изображения, а используется только для сохранения по клику мышкой на `PictureBox`. Исходное изображение в формате `.png` будет сохранено в файл `test.gif` в формате `.gif`.